# Recreating NTILE function on running SQL in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, plsqldeveloper

I am making a conversion from traditional way of creating reports in Excel, and I have been stuck on recreating NTILE function when running SQL in Excel (because NTILE function does not exist there), even though I have succeeded in recreating NTILE function when running in Oracle PL/SQL Developer.

Traditional way:

- SQL scripts are stored in an Excel sheet.
- I write macro to connect to Oracle database, then open a recordset with SQL scripts, and copy that recordset to another Excel sheet.

New way:

- SQL scripts are stored in an Excel sheet.
- A table in Oracle database is saved as a csv file on a hard disk.
- I write macro to connect to the csv file (not open it) using Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0, then open a record set with SQL scripts, and copy that recordset to another Excel sheet.

In the new way, SQL scripts are modified because some functions and statements in Oracle do not exist when running SQL in Excel (example: NTILE, REMAINDER, TRUNC, CASE). NTILE is rewritten; REMAINDER becomes MOD; TRUNC becomes INT; CASE becomes IIF.

Below is my SQL script of:

1. Creating a sample table
2. NTILE result
3. Recreating NTILE function in Oracle (as intermediate step)
4. Recreating NTILE function in Excel SQL

```sql
    CREATE TABLE testntile
                 (
                 appid NUMBER(2),
                 sample VARCHAR2(50),
                 score NUMBER(3)
                 );

    INSERT ALL
      INTO testntile (appid, sample, score) VALUES (5, 'A', 4)
      INTO testntile (appid, sample, score) VALUES (2, 'B', 6)
      INTO testntile (appid, sample, score) VALUES (3, 'C', 8)
      INTO testntile (appid, sample, score) VALUES (1, 'C', 1)
      INTO testntile (appid, sample, score) VALUES (4, 'B', 2)
      INTO testntile (appid, sample, score) VALUES (8, 'C', 3)
      INTO testntile (appid, sample, score) VALUES (6, 'C', 8)
      INTO testntile (appid, sample, score) VALUES (9, 'B', 9)
      INTO testntile (appid, sample, score) VALUES (7, 'C', 7)
      INTO testntile (appid, sample, score) VALUES (10, 'B', 5)
      INTO testntile (appid, sample, score) VALUES (14, 'A', 2)
      INTO testntile (appid, sample, score) VALUES (12, 'C', 7)
      INTO testntile (appid, sample, score) VALUES (13, 'C', 7)
      INTO testntile (appid, sample, score) VALUES (11, 'A', 9)
      INTO testntile (appid, sample, score) VALUES (15, 'C', 3)
      INTO testntile (appid, sample, score) VALUES (16, 'C', 12)
      INTO testntile (appid, sample, score) VALUES (18, 'C', 12)
      INTO testntile (appid, sample, score) VALUES (17, 'C', 16)
      INTO testntile (appid, sample, score) VALUES (19, 'C', 12)
      INTO testntile (appid, sample, score) VALUES (20, 'D', 14)
      INTO testntile (appid, sample, score) VALUES (21, 'D', 11)
    SELECT * FROM dual;
    COMMIT;

    -- desired NTILE result
    SELECT
          NTILE(3) OVER (PARTITION BY sample ORDER BY score) RangeList,
          s.* 
    FROM testntile s;

    -- Recreating NTILE function in Oracle
    -- (as intermediate step to recreate NTILE function in Excel SQL)
    SELECT 
          CASE WHEN REMAINDER(
                               (SELECT count(t2.appid)
                                FROM testntile t2
                                WHERE t2.sample = t1.sample)
                              ,3) <> 0 
               THEN CASE WHEN ((SELECT count(t2.appid)
                                FROM testntile t2
                                WHERE t2.sample = t1.sample) / 3) < 1
                         THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) +1
                               FROM testntile t2
                               WHERE t2.sample = t1.sample
                                     AND (t2.score < t1.score OR (t2.score = t1.score AND t2.appid < t1.appid))                
                              )
                         ELSE 1 + TRUNC((SELECT COUNT(*)
                                         FROM testntile t2
                                         WHERE t2.sample = t1.sample
                                         AND (t2.score < t1.score OR (t2.score = t1.score AND t2.appid < t1.appid))                
                                        ) / ((SELECT count(t2.appid)
                                              FROM testntile t2
                                              WHERE t2.sample = t1.sample) / 3)) 
                    END
               ELSE CASE WHEN ((SELECT count(t2.appid)
                                FROM testntile t2
                                WHERE t2.sample = t1.sample) / 3) = 1
                         THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) +1
                               FROM testntile t2
                               WHERE t2.sample = t1.sample
                                     AND (t2.score < t1.score OR (t2.score = t1.score AND t2.appid < t1.appid))                
                              )
                         ELSE 1 + TRUNC((SELECT COUNT(*)
                                         FROM testntile t2
                                         WHERE t2.sample = t1.sample
                                         AND (t2.score < t1.score OR (t2.score = t1.score AND t2.appid < t1.appid))                
                                        ) / ((SELECT count(t2.appid)
                                              FROM testntile t2
                                              WHERE t2.sample = t1.sample) / 3))
                    END
          END RangeList,
       t1.appid,
       t1.sample,
       t1.score
    FROM
       testntile t1
    ORDER BY
       t1.sample,
       t1.score,
       t1.appid

    -- Recreating NTILE function in Excel SQL
    SELECT 
          IIf(MOD(
                  (SELECT count(t2.appid)
                   FROM &Selected_Table t2
                   WHERE t2.sample = t1.sample)
                  ,3) <> 0 
                  , IIf( ((SELECT count(t2.appid)
                           FROM &Selected_Table t2
                           WHERE t2.sample = t1.sample) / 3) < 1
                         , (SELECT COUNT(*) +1
                            FROM &Selected_Table t2
                            WHERE t2.sample = t1.sample
                                  AND (t2.score < t1.score OR (t2.score = t1.score AND t2.appid < t1.appid))                
                           )
                         , 1 + INT((SELECT COUNT(*)
                                    FROM &Selected_Table t2
                                    WHERE t2.sample = t1.sample
                                          AND (t2.score < t1.score OR (t2.score = t1.score AND t2.appid < t1.appid))                
                                   ) / ((SELECT count(t2.appid)
                                         FROM &Selected_Table t2
                                         WHERE t2.sample = t1.sample) / 3)) 
                       )
                  , IIf( ((SELECT count(t2.appid)
                           FROM &Selected_Table t2
                           WHERE t2.sample = t1.sample) / 3) = 1
                         , (SELECT COUNT(*) +1
                            FROM &Selected_Table t2
                            WHERE t2.sample = t1.sample
                                  AND (t2.score < t1.score OR (t2.score = t1.score AND t2.appid < t1.appid))                
                           )
                         , 1 + INT((SELECT COUNT(*)
                                    FROM &Selected_Table t2
                                    WHERE t2.sample = t1.sample
                                          AND (t2.score < t1.score OR (t2.score = t1.score AND t2.appid < t1.appid))                
                                   ) / ((SELECT count(t2.appid)
                                         FROM &Selected_Table t2
                                         WHERE t2.sample = t1.sample) / 3))
                       )
              ) RangeList,
       t1.appid,
       t1.sample,
       t1.score
    FROM
       &Selected_Table t1
    ORDER BY
       t1.sample,
       t1.score,
       t1.appid
```

In summary, SQL script in the traditional way is the part of -- desired NTILE result above.

And SQL script in the new way is the part of -- Recreating NTILE function in Excel SQL above.

Make sure that file testntile.csv is available as description of testntile table above.

Finally, here are VBA sheets, subs and functions.

For sheets I use their code name, not sheet name.

- shSQLList : contain SQL script (of new way) in cell A1
- shResult : store result data

For subs and functions, just put them all in a module.

```vb
    Option Explicit

    Public strPath As String
    Public strTable As String

    Public Contn As New ADODB.Connection

    Sub test()

    Dim SQL As String
    Dim rRange As Range

        'let the user choose files needed for making a report
        strPath = BrowseFileExplorer(, , ThisWorkbook.Path)
        If strPath = vbNullString Then 'user cancelled
            MsgBox "No file selected."
        Else 'user picked a file
            strPath = RemoveTrailingSlash(strPath)
            strTable = Right(strPath, Len(strPath) - InStrRev(strPath, "\"))

            'if file name contains underscore, ask the user to remove underscore
            If InStr(1, strTable, "_", vbTextCompare) Then
                MsgBox "SQL in Excel cannot run with underscore(s) in file name." & vbCrLf & _
                        "Please remove all underscores from the csv file, then run the macro again.", _
                        vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        SQL = ""
        Set rRange = Nothing

        SQL = shSQLList.Range("A1").Value
        SQL = Replace(SQL, "&Selected_Table", "[" & strTable & "]")
        'table name needs enclosing in [ ] if it has space or special characters
        'to run SQL in Excel, table name cannot contain underscore
        Set rRange = shResult.Range("A1")

        Call ImportCSVfile(SQL, strPath, rRange.Cells(1, 1))
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Sub

    Function BrowseFileExplorer(Optional DialogTitle As String = "Select a file", _
        Optional ViewType As Office.MsoFileDialogView = MsoFileDialogView.msoFileDialogViewSmallIcons, _
        Optional InitialDirectory As String) As String
    'Other option:
    'ViewType As Office.MsoFileDialogView = msoFileDialogViewList

    Dim fDialog As Office.FileDialog
    Dim varFile As Variant

    Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With fDialog
        .Title = DialogTitle
        .InitialView = ViewType
        .ButtonName = "&Select"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "CSV", "*.csv"

        If Dir(InitialDirectory, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then
            If Right(InitialDirectory, 1) <> "\" Then
                InitialDirectory = InitialDirectory & "\"
            End If
            .InitialFileName = InitialDirectory
        Else
            .InitialFileName = CurDir
        End If

        If .Show = True Then
            ' user picked a file
            BrowseFileExplorer = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            ' user cancelled
            BrowseFileExplorer = vbNullString
        End If
    End With

    End Function

    Public Function TrailingSlash(strFolder As String) As String

    If Len(strFolder) > 0 Then
        If Right(strFolder, 1) = "\" Then
            TrailingSlash = strFolder
        Else
            TrailingSlash = strFolder & "\"
        End If
    End If

    End Function

    Public Function RemoveTrailingSlash(strFile As String) As String

    If Len(strFile) > 0 Then
        If Right(strFile, 1) = "\" Then
            RemoveTrailingSlash = Left(strFile, Len(strFile) - 1)
        Else
            RemoveTrailingSlash = strFile
        End If
    End If

    End Function

    Sub ImportCSVfile(SQL As String, sPath As String, Destination As Range)

    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '  NOTE: Requires reference to ADO library:
    '     1. Open the Visual Basic Editor (Alt + Fll)
    '     2. Choose Tools | References
    '     3. Select the checkbox for Microsoft ActiveX Data Object 2.5 Library (or higher)
    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Dim RcdSet As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim fldRS As ADODB.Field
    Dim i As Integer

        Set Contn = New ADODB.Connection
        'for before Excel 2007 to open .xls file
    '    Contn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & sPath & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES"";"

        'for Excel 2007 or later to open .xls file
    '    Contn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & sPath & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES"";"

        'for Excel 2007 or later to open .xlsx file
    '    Contn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & sPath & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"

        'for all Excel versions to open .csv file
        'get the folder path with trailing slash
        sPath = Left(sPath, InStrRev(sPath, "\", , vbTextCompare))
        Contn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & sPath & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"";"
        'HDR=Yes indicates that the first row contains column names, not data

        Set RcdSet = New ADODB.Recordset

        'If you are using an SQL statement with an ADO recordset,
        'make sure that the final parameter for the Open method is adCmdText (not adCmdTable)
        RcdSet.Open SQL, Contn, CursorTypeEnum.adOpenForwardOnly, _
                    LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly, CommandTypeEnum.adCmdText

        Destination.CopyFromRecordset RcdSet

        RcdSet.Close
        Set RcdSet = Nothing

        Contn.Close
        Set Contn = Nothing

    End Sub
```

While I can run SQL script of recreating NTILE function in Oracle PL/SQL Developer successfully (same result as NTILE function), I always get error when running SQL script in Excel, even though I tried to shorten SQL statement to only one simple SELECT IIf( ).

I have spent a lot of time on this task but without success. Please help me and I really appreciate your kind support.

Comment: Why are you not sticking with the traditional way?

Comment: Hi Boneist, because I am asked to save tables as csv files, and then run macro on these csv files using similar SQL script. I do not want to reinvent the wheel, but it is the job I was assigned.